# How should I use GDAL to perform a transformation?

Tags: python, gdal, coordinate-system

I am a student who wishes to use GDAL to transform a series of images from Lambert Conformal Conic (EPSG: 9802) to Google Earth's WGS 84 (EPSG: 4326) for a web mapping project.  I know that in order to perform this operation I need to use gdaltransform, which is an executable that can be used via command line.

My issue is not being able to wrap my head around how to use gdaltransform correctly.  I have read several documents that source this link http://gdal.org/gdaltransform.html, but I have been unable to replicate the tutorial results.  Can someone please help me understand what I am missing.

**Source Code:**
*This code is what I typed in replicate the demo found on the above link.*

Input:   `gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:9802 -t_srs EPSG:4326`

Return:  `0 0 0`

Input:   `177502 311865`

Return:  `177502 311865 0`

*Note:  The return should read `244510.77404604 166154.532871342 -1046.79270555763` not `177502 311865 0`*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, you will want [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html), not gdaltransform.  There are lots of examples out there.

For example,

```
gdalwarp -t_srs 'EPSG:4326' input.tif output.tif
```

Comment: You might want to edit this to match your quotes.

Comment: By any chance would you know how to call this in Python?

Comment: import subprocess

Comment: subprocess.call(["gdalwarp", "-t_srs", "EPSG:4326", "input.tif", "output.tif"])

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you for your help!  However, I do have one last question.

Comment: How would I go about setting the function to know where the input Tiff is located and where to write the file?  Also, does the output Tiff need to previously exist or will it be generated when this function is called?

Answer (score 4):

EPSG:9802 is an operation (map projection) method, not a complete coordinate reference system definition. There's not enough information for gdaltransform to work. Can you identify the data's current coordinate reference system? You can do a search by area at the [online EPSG registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) or download a Microsoft Access database version, [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset](http://www.epsg.org).

The example that you referenced is:

> gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:28992 -t_srs
>   EPSG:31370
>
> 177502 311865
>
> Produces the following output in
>   meters in the "Belge 1972 / Belgian
>   Lambert 72" projection:
>
> 244510.77404604 166154.532871342 -1046.79270555763

In this case, the input is EPSG:28992, "Amersfoort / RD New", not EPSG:9802.

Comment: That you mkennedy, I found your post to be rather informative and resourceful!