# Converting dataset between coordinate systems

Tags: raster, resampling, modis

I'm working with NOAA's [PRECipitation REConstruction over Land](http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.NOAA/.NCEP/.CPC/.PRECL/) dataset, and am looking for an efficient way to sample the data by pixels on NASA's MODIS grid, using open source tools. The PRECL data uses 0.5 degree blocks, so I'll have quite a few repeated values.

I'm currently using a mapping generated by ArcGIS that specifies the array index within the PRECL data for every MODIS pixel. This works (and it's fast, as I'm just doing a series of array lookups), but it'd be nice to get away from that extra data set, especially if there were some way to do the transformation in code, without Arc.

Thanks in advance, all!

Comment: did you notice this similar question? Does it help your situation?  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5041/how-should-i-use-gdal-to-perform-a-transformation

Comment: IF not. I use auotdesk raster design which does contain a function to resample/transform by pixel. It has several methods. Arcgis as well has an extension called spatial analyst. If you have access to that it will resample to a new dataset and you can specify from several methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[R](http://www.r-project.org) is an excellent programming language designed for data manipulation and statistical computation.  There is a very nice package called [sp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html) that adds good support for handling spatial data.  The `spsample` function can pull a statistical sample from spatial data using 7 different methods.  The sampling area may be controlled by specifying a bounding box and/or a grid cell size.

Combine with the [rgdal](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) package for geospatial IO and you should be ready to rock.

Comment: I find the `maptools` R package very useful (it depends on the sp package). You can read a raster directly in using it (I haven't used `sp` so perhaps you can also do it there also)

Comment: Hey, I'll take it. R is great, though I'm working on moving to Incanter, using Clojure.